# Script block of Start-Job hang in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following script. The created background job never finishes. (It finishes in a few seconds if I just run the scripts in the `-ScriptBlock { ... }`).

**Edit:**
My machine is XP/sp3. This may be the reason of hang as Jon found out.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Sql* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
    {
        Add-PSSnapin Sql*
    }
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select 1 a" -ServerInstance serverX -ErrorAction stop
}
```

`Receive-Job *` returns nothing and `Get-Job` always returns the following lines.

```
> Get-Job

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------                  
29              Job29           Running    True            localhost            ...
```

Comment: I just tried your example locally on a 2008 x64 VM with SQL Server 2008 and it didn't hang for me. You might want to try putting some logging in script block: `"No Sql* snapins loaded, Loading..." | out-file C:\Log.txt -Append"` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems to be working in my test environment (Windows 7). You might be experiencing [this (Background jobs keep running infinitely in Win XP SP3)](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/682459/background-jobs-keep-running-infinitely-in-win-xp-sp3) on Windows XP/2003.

Comment: It seems Windows server 2003 also has the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you're hitting *this* bug:

http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/499499/adding-a-snapin-add-pssnapin-from-within-a-job-start-job-causes-job-to-hang-indefinitely

...which is apparently because of: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009703

Comment: Looks like the two connect bugs are referring to the same problem... Oh my! Good finds guys. Solution is upgrade your OS :-)